# Differences between tesing multi-thread in JUnit and Main function in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I tested a multi-thread program in JUnit and main function, source code as follows:

```
public class TestDaemon {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("hello");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        // default false
        thread.setDaemon(false);
        thread.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("hello");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        // default false
        thread.setDaemon(false);
        thread.start();

    }
}
```

It didn't print `hello` string in the JUnit test example.
In the main function example, it could print `hello` in the console, but when I set the `thread.setDaemon(true)`, it also can't print `hello`.

> I know this is related to `Daemon thred` and `User thread`, but I don't know how to explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A daemon thread is a thread that does not prevent the JVM from exiting when the program finishes but the thread is still running. An example for a daemon thread is the garbage collection.

When you run your code from main it creates both beans, thus two threads - daemon and non-daemon. As long as non-daemon thread is running, your application won't exit. So it works.

It's different when run from JUnit. As soon as JUnit test method completes (and it completes immediately after the Spring context is up), JUnit assumes your tests are done. Thus it kills all your threads and basically the whole JVM.

Remember your Waitor1 bean spawns a background thread which JUnit doesn't care about. As soon as you leave @Test method JUnit will just stop everything.

Comment: To extend the implications of this answer, your test case needs to actually wait for your thread to do what it's going to do -- and probably actually test something. You'll need some sort of logic in test() that actually understands when the test has completed so it can exit. You have to interact with your started thread in some way. This can be your thread setting a variable when it's about to exit, and your test() program watching for that variable. (I'd use a mutex lock and a condition variable.) Your real world problem defines what you really do.

Answer (score 0):

We can analyze the source code of JUnit, part of `junit.textui.TestRunner` as follows:

```
public static final int SUCCESS_EXIT = 0;
public static final int FAILURE_EXIT = 1;
public static final int EXCEPTION_EXIT = 2;

...

public static void main(String args[]) {
    TestRunner aTestRunner = new TestRunner();
    try {
        TestResult r = aTestRunner.start(args);
        if (!r.wasSuccessful()) {
            System.exit(FAILURE_EXIT);
        }
        System.exit(SUCCESS_EXIT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(EXCEPTION_EXIT);
    }
}
/**
 * Returns whether the entire test was successful or not.
 */
public synchronized boolean wasSuccessful() {
    return failureCount() == 0 && errorCount() == 0;
}
/**
 * Gets the number of detected failures.
 */
public synchronized int failureCount() {
    return fFailures.size();
}
/**
 * Gets the number of detected errors.
 */
public synchronized int errorCount() {
    return fErrors.size();
}
```

In this source code, we can conclude that the TestRunner excutes the `Unit Test method`, no need to wait it finish their tasks, then calls `System.exit()` method, so that terminates the program. So, it couldn't print `hello` in the console.

In the main function,  because the new thread is not daemon thread, the main program will wait it finishing their tasks, then teminates the program. So,`hello`string could be seen in the console.